# How to get out of my infinite loop in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, infinite-loop

So I have a 2 form application. The first form you enter in a quote of the day and press a button that opens the second form with the text displayed in the label. You then press a button and the text continuously scrolls across the screen using an infinite loop. It obviously hangs the program. I want to be able to have the text sit there scrolling until someone wants to stop it with a button click or something... I'm pretty sure that you have to do it with a thread, I just am new and don't really know much about threading...
Here is my infinite loop that I call with the button click...

```
private void StartScroll()
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(label2.Text + " ");

        while (true)
        {

            char ch = sb[0];
            sb.Remove(0, 1);
            sb.Insert( sb.Length , ch);
            label2.Text = sb.ToString();
            label2.Refresh();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);


        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Considering how new to this you are.. have you considered using a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` control? That may be easier than delving directly into threading..

Comment: take a look at the background worker class

Comment: Instead of `while (true)`, place a `Timer` on your Form and set the `Interval` property to 100.  Be sure to `Start` the Timer in StartScroll() and handle the `Tick` event which is where you'll place the scrolling logic.

Comment: I've never heard of the timer... I'll look into it and the background worker class as well

Comment: Does someone mind demonstrating this with a timer? I'm reading and I don't really understand where to put it

Comment: The Timer is in your ToolBox along with the other controls.  I think it's towards the bottom.  Just drop one on your form and set the properties then double click it (down below the form) to get the Tick() event handler.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this site for the background worker. It's really easy to implement and should be able to take care of your issue.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

Comment: A `Timer` is much handier in this case, the `Tick` is being executed in the UI thread rather than a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a timer that ticks every 100ms. Example:

```
//Create a new timer that ticks every 100ms
var t = new System.Timers.Timer (100);

//When a tick is elapsed
t.Elapsed+=(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) => 
{
   //what ever you want to do
};
//Start the timer
t.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need your text scrooling through the form(if i understood you correctly),you can try this.TextSize is the size of the text,x represents the x axis of the form you can change this if you need.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb;
private int x,TextSize;

public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(label2.Text + " ");
     x = this.ClientRectangle.Width;
     TextSize = 16;
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Tag = sb.ToString();
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}

void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1_Paint(this,null);
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{

     string str = timer1.Tag.ToString();
     Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle);
     g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
     g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, this.ClientRectangle);
     g.DrawString(str, new Font("Arial", TextSize), new SolidBrush(Color.White), x, 5);
     x -= 5;

     if (x <= str.Length * TextSize * -1)
         x = this.ClientRectangle.Width;

    }
```

and to stop the timer

```
    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
```